# SharePoint 2016 access files for anonymous R/W access

Tags: sharepoint, anonymous, on-premises-instances

I have a SharePoint 2016 server behind VPN. How to enable anonymous read-write access for stored files.

I've set anonymous access to entire website but without success:
[Sharepoint configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFD21.png)
but when I'm trying to open directly in Word from link like:
`ms-word:ofe|u|http://sharepoint.com/library/library/xxx/xxx-b65a2294-d014-4f18-9686-99d169b805ee-basedocument-0.docx`
system is still asking me for creds
[Word credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qpYD.png)
What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this article to solve your problem: [You're prompted for credentials when you open documents anonymously in SharePoint Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/receive-credentials-prompting)